# GSON library not found when importing into processing java

Tags: java, import, gson, processing

I'm trying to import the GSON library into my processing java sketch. The editor I'm using is VS Code. I'm fairly new to how libraries work in Java, so I followed what many sites said. Here's what I did.

1. First, I downloaded the GSON `.jar` file from [this site](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/).
2. Next, In my processing sketch within VS Code, I created folders called `libraries` and `library`, so that the file structure looked like this: `/sketch/libraries/library`.
3. Then, I renamed the downloaded file from step 1 to `gson.jar` and put it in both the `libraries` then `library` folder.
4. Finally, I imported the libraries at the top of my sketch like so:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

However, I still get the library not found error:

> No library found for com.google.gson
> No library found for com.google.gson
> Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the sketchbook folder (see the Preferences window).
> main.pde:0:0:0:0: The package “com.google” does not exist. You might be missing a library.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a step?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option would be to drop gson-2.8.2.jar into a Processing sketch.
This will create a code folder with the jar inside the import should work from there:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

println(Gson.class);// prints class com.google.gson.Gson
```

The downside is the jar is visible per sketch.

If you want the library to be visible to all sketches as if it's a Processing library, as you've attempt, the folder structure is slightly different:

/path/to/Processing/libraries/YourLibrary/library/YourLibrary.jar

e.g. Documents/Processing/libraries/Gson/library/Gson.jar

(indeed you need to rename gson-2.8.2.jar to match the grandparent folder name)

Additionally, if you don't mind a simpler JSON parser, just uses the built-in [`loadJSONObject()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html) / [`loadJSONArray()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONArray_.html) functions